# How do I setup and alternate directory structure for django?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting on my first large django project and have realized that the default directory structure isn't going to work well.

I saw this question and answer and decided to implement something similar.
[Large Django application layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670031/large-django-application-layout/2670177#2670177)

**What do I need to do to make something like this work? How can I change where django looks for apps/modules?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python works automatically with deep directory structures. That's porbably you didn't find any instructions on how to do it.Here are some instructions on how to get classes and models to work.

If you want to have a module in folder `yourproject/apps/firstapp` you can just add it to INSTALLED_APPS by adding line `'apps.firstapp',`. You will have to add a `__init__.py` file to each of the directories so that they are recognized as python packages.

When you import classes you can simply use `from yourproject.apps.firstapp.filename import yourclass`.

You should also make sure all template directories are listed in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me? I just get Error: No module named dir.app
Does the containing folder need to be an app as well?

Comment: Forgot to mention. You should add empty `__init__.py` file to the folder so that python recognizes it as a module.

Comment: This seems to work with runserver, but when I use apache and wsgi it gives me not found errors. Then it works Ryans solution, but that seems to have problems when dealing with apps outside of the settings.py

Answer (score 1):

I have two methods to handle this; one for production and one for development.

**In development:**
Append the path to your apps in your `settings.py`.  In my case, I have my main project in `~/hg/django/project/` and my apps are in `~/hg/django/apps/`.  So I use:

```
if DEVEL:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'apps'))
```

I also use the production method on my development box.  This method has a knock on effect of letting me roll back to the most recent production version by simply commenting out the line path insertion in the `settings.py`.

**In production:**
I install the apps using `distutils` so that I can control deployment per server, and multiple projects running on each server can all access them.  You can read about [the `distutils` setup scripts](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html) here.  Then, to install, you simply:

```
./setup.py install
```

Comment: Another good answer, but Lycha's was simpler to implement for now.

Answer (score 1):

if you add:

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

to your settings .py and the following to your manage.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "lib"))
```

then you can include them in your installed apps just as you would if they were in your project root:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #local apps
    'myapp',

    #local libs
    'piston_dev',
)
```

this allows you a bit more freedom to move apps around without having to redeclare imports and such.