# Directory structure for large django rest framework apps

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We've been developing an application using **django** and **django rest framework** for a while now and we're reaching a point where our viewsets.py and serializers.py files are getting too large.

Our current structure is very similar to what many posts describe (eg. [Large Django application layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670031/large-django-application-layout)) but they only seem to suggest creating new applications as the best route to maintaining manageable directories.

Our current set up is as follows:

```
project
    app1
        models.py
        serializers.py
        viewsets.py
        ...
    app2
        models.py
        serializers.py
        viewsets.py
        ...
```

For our use case, our models.py are small and discrete enough that I don't think we need to separate them out into separate applications, but I'm not sure what else we can do.

Comment: What's your programming question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking here. Neither Django nor Django Rest Framework accord any special status to the file serializers.py; like views.py, it's just a place where you store things that are imported by other functions. So it's absolutely fine to split that file up in any way you like.

For instance, you could have a serializers package, ie a directory with many Python files in it (including a possibly-empty `__init__.py`); you could simply have variously named files in the app directory with different serializer classes in them; and so on.

Comment: Hey, what about `models.py`? I mean what are the best practices to split up your models into individual files? I am imagining a single file for the model, viewset and serializers for each entity of my application. What do you think about this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Either split your app into sub application based on usage as mention above.

are you can split it based database like,

```
app->
    tables->
      models.py
      viewset.py
      serializer.py
    views->
      models.py
      viewset.py
      serializer.py
    procedures->
      models.py
      viewset.py
      serializer.py
```